# Bootstrap.dat on Mac OSX 10.9 - Difficulty

Tags: bitcoin-core

Been trawling through a lot of information (I know this similar issue has probably come up a fair bit) on this issue and going round in circles a bit. I am not the most tech savvy individual, and would be really grateful if someone could has some advice that could save me time.

Here is where I am at:

- I have a Mac running OSX 10.9.2
- I have downloaded and installed the Bitcoin-QT. The synching process was just getting started and I have subsequently quit the application and downloaded the `bootstrap.dat` file - this torrent is currently downloading via the Deluge application.

Thinking ahead, I have read a bit about where to place this dat file once it has downloaded. For starters, I cannot seem to locate the `~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/` on my mac? and I also tried the `/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin` but could not find anything. From selecting the 'Show Package Contents' for the Bitcoin-QT application itself, should I be creating a folder in here manually?

I'd massively grateful for any tips.

John

Comment: Since version 0.10 blockchain download speed has been drastically increased and I would advise letting it bring itself up to date rather than trusting and working with a torrent. N.B. Some reports indicate if updating from <0.10 blockchain update crawls but can be fixed by quitting, deleting the old blockchain and starting over. Make sure to backup your wallet.

Answer (score 0):

In the Finder, click the 'Go' menu and choose 'Go to folder' (or just cmd-shift-G)
type

```
~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/
```

in the field that appears, click go and viola. If you've never previously run bitcoin the directory won't be there but you can go to

```
~/Library/Application Support/
```

and create it.

the problem you were having trying to find it if you were using the Terminal to do so may have been that spaces have to be escaped in file paths, so the command to change to that directory would be

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Bitcoin
```

note the backslash before the space. As I've noted you know, you can also drag files or folders in to the Terminal and it will automatically enter the path to that file/folder.